# Understanding AlamoFire OAuth Example

Tags: ios, swift, oauth, swift3, alamofire

I was able to get a working implementation of OAuth example as provided by AlamoFire. However, I am looking to understand certain lines of code and how it works.

Full Example:

```
class OAuth2Handler: RequestAdapter, RequestRetrier {
    private typealias RefreshCompletion = (_ succeeded: Bool, _ accessToken: String?, _ refreshToken: String?) -> Void

    private let sessionManager: SessionManager = {
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        configuration.httpAdditionalHeaders = SessionManager.defaultHTTPHeaders

        return SessionManager(configuration: configuration)
    }()

    private let lock = NSLock()

    private var clientID: String
    private var baseURLString: String
    private var accessToken: String
    private var refreshToken: String

    private var isRefreshing = false
    private var requestsToRetry: [RequestRetryCompletion] = []

    // MARK: - Initialization

    public init(clientID: String, baseURLString: String, accessToken: String, refreshToken: String) {
        self.clientID = clientID
        self.baseURLString = baseURLString
        self.accessToken = accessToken
        self.refreshToken = refreshToken
    }

    // MARK: - RequestAdapter

    func adapt(_ urlRequest: URLRequest) throws -> URLRequest {
        if let urlString = urlRequest.url?.absoluteString, urlString.hasPrefix(baseURLString) {
            var urlRequest = urlRequest
            urlRequest.setValue("Bearer " + accessToken, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
            return urlRequest
        }

        return urlRequest
    }

    // MARK: - RequestRetrier

    func should(_ manager: SessionManager, retry request: Request, with error: Error, completion: @escaping RequestRetryCompletion) {
        lock.lock() ; defer { lock.unlock() }

        if let response = request.task?.response as? HTTPURLResponse, response.statusCode == 401 {
            requestsToRetry.append(completion)

            if !isRefreshing {
                refreshTokens { [weak self] succeeded, accessToken, refreshToken in
                    guard let strongSelf = self else { return }

                    strongSelf.lock.lock() ; defer { strongSelf.lock.unlock() }

                    if let accessToken = accessToken, let refreshToken = refreshToken {
                        strongSelf.accessToken = accessToken
                        strongSelf.refreshToken = refreshToken
                    }

                    strongSelf.requestsToRetry.forEach { $0(succeeded, 0.0) }
                    strongSelf.requestsToRetry.removeAll()
                }
            }
        } else {
            completion(false, 0.0)
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Private - Refresh Tokens

    private func refreshTokens(completion: @escaping RefreshCompletion) {
        guard !isRefreshing else { return }

        isRefreshing = true

        let urlString = "\(baseURLString)/oauth2/token"

        let parameters: [String: Any] = [
            "access_token": accessToken,
            "refresh_token": refreshToken,
            "client_id": clientID,
            "grant_type": "refresh_token"
        ]

        sessionManager.request(urlString, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
            .responseJSON { [weak self] response in
                guard let strongSelf = self else { return }

                if 
                    let json = response.result.value as? [String: Any], 
                    let accessToken = json["access_token"] as? String, 
                    let refreshToken = json["refresh_token"] as? String 
                {
                    completion(true, accessToken, refreshToken)
                } else {
                    completion(false, nil, nil)
                }

                strongSelf.isRefreshing = false
            }
    }
}
```

Questions:

```
[weak self] succeeded, accessToken, refreshToken in
                    guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
```

1. What is the purpose of `[weak self]` and the `guard` for `strongSelf`?

   ```
       requestsToRetry.append(completion)

       if !isRefreshing {
           refreshTokens { [weak self] succeeded, accessToken, refreshToken in
               guard let strongSelf = self else { return }

               //Implementation

               strongSelf.requestsToRetry.forEach { $0(succeeded, 0.0) }
               strongSelf.requestsToRetry.removeAll()
           }
       }
   ```
2. How does this request retry work? The `requestsToRetry` is just an array of `RequestRetryCompletion = (_ shouldRetry: Bool, _ timeDelay: TimeInterval)` How does it know what requests to retry?

`strongSelf.lock.lock()`

3. Does `NSLock` just not allow `self` (OAuth2Handler) to be accessed by any other thread while this method is executing?

Comment: 1 is so that you get a strong reference to `self` so that the following code wont try to use `self` if its nil because `self` in that context is weak, the strong reference will be released at the end of the scope so no retain cycles would happen. Not familiar with alamofire so cant say for certain what the rest are.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1) Exactly as commented by Fonix, you have a strong reference to `self`to avoid that if `self` was nil you start to collect retain cycles..

I'm refeer to :

```
[weak self] ... in
guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
```

Since `self` will be captured in the block which is dispatched asynchronously, `self` will be implicitly retained and released again when the block has been finished, in other words `self` will be extended up until after the block finishes. Making this code, you avoid to extend the life-time of `self` and decide to don't execute the block if `self` is equal to nil

2) According to the lines you mentioned:

```
if let response = request.task?.response as? HTTPURLResponse, response.statusCode == 401 {
            requestsToRetry.append(completion)
            ..
```

there is an array called `requestsToRetry` which contains all the request you need to relaunch. In this code you append to the array all the request that have the `401` status code (when server returns status code 401)
With the code `forEach` you loop through the `requestToRetry` array:

```
strongSelf.requestsToRetry.forEach { $0(succeeded, 0.0) }
strongSelf.requestsToRetry.removeAll()
```

and launch all items. After the cycle is concluded you remove all the items.

In fact, the sources report:

```
public typealias RequestRetryCompletion = (_ shouldRetry: Bool, _ timeDelay: TimeInterval) -> Void

public protocol RequestRetrier {
    func should(_ manager: SessionManager, retry request: Request, with error: Error, completion: @escaping RequestRetryCompletion)
}
```

You can find more details [here](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%204.0%20Migration%20Guide.md)

3) Exactly as you said the frequently concurrency issues faced are the one related to accessing/modifying the shared resource from different threads.
The `lock.lock()` is a solution to lock the other execution blocks when items is being modified. The code in `defer` is called just before leaving the function to unlocking the block.