# I need help to port code to Alamofire 5.0

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I want to implement OAuth2 in swift. I've heard about Alamofire so I've search accros internet some implementation.

Finaly, I found a post on Stackoverflow whith a piece of code here : [Understanding AlamoFire OAuth Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42079180/understanding-alamofire-oauth-example)

```
class OAuth2Handler: RequestAdapter, RequestRetrier {
    private typealias RefreshCompletion = (_ succeeded: Bool, _ accessToken: String?, _ refreshToken: String?) -> Void

    private let sessionManager: SessionManager = {
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        configuration.httpAdditionalHeaders = SessionManager.defaultHTTPHeaders

        return SessionManager(configuration: configuration)
    }()

    private let lock = NSLock()

    private var clientID: String
    private var baseURLString: String
    private var accessToken: String
    private var refreshToken: String

    private var isRefreshing = false
    private var requestsToRetry: [RequestRetryCompletion] = []

    // MARK: - Initialization

    public init(clientID: String, baseURLString: String, accessToken: String, refreshToken: String) {
        self.clientID = clientID
        self.baseURLString = baseURLString
        self.accessToken = accessToken
        self.refreshToken = refreshToken
    }

    // MARK: - RequestAdapter

    func adapt(_ urlRequest: URLRequest) throws -> URLRequest {
        if let urlString = urlRequest.url?.absoluteString, urlString.hasPrefix(baseURLString) {
            var urlRequest = urlRequest
            urlRequest.setValue("Bearer " + accessToken, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
            return urlRequest
        }

        return urlRequest
    }

    // MARK: - RequestRetrier

    func should(_ manager: SessionManager, retry request: Request, with error: Error, completion: @escaping RequestRetryCompletion) {
        lock.lock() ; defer { lock.unlock() }

        if let response = request.task?.response as? HTTPURLResponse, response.statusCode == 401 {
            requestsToRetry.append(completion)

            if !isRefreshing {
                refreshTokens { [weak self] succeeded, accessToken, refreshToken in
                    guard let strongSelf = self else { return }

                    strongSelf.lock.lock() ; defer { strongSelf.lock.unlock() }

                    if let accessToken = accessToken, let refreshToken = refreshToken {
                        strongSelf.accessToken = accessToken
                        strongSelf.refreshToken = refreshToken
                    }

                    strongSelf.requestsToRetry.forEach { $0(succeeded, 0.0) }
                    strongSelf.requestsToRetry.removeAll()
                }
            }
        } else {
            completion(false, 0.0)
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Private - Refresh Tokens

    private func refreshTokens(completion: @escaping RefreshCompletion) {
        guard !isRefreshing else { return }

        isRefreshing = true

        let urlString = "\(baseURLString)/oauth2/token"

        let parameters: [String: Any] = [
            "access_token": accessToken,
            "refresh_token": refreshToken,
            "client_id": clientID,
            "grant_type": "refresh_token"
        ]

        sessionManager.request(urlString, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
            .responseJSON { [weak self] response in
                guard let strongSelf = self else { return }

                if 
                    let json = response.result.value as? [String: Any], 
                    let accessToken = json["access_token"] as? String, 
                    let refreshToken = json["refresh_token"] as? String 
                {
                    completion(true, accessToken, refreshToken)
                } else {
                    completion(false, nil, nil)
                }

                strongSelf.isRefreshing = false
            }
    }
}
```

The problem is that it has been coded whith Alamofire 4 and so it won't compile anymore whith the latest version of Alamofire
Can someone help me to port it to AlamoFire 5

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Actually I've download Alamofire 4.9.1 and it works like a charm